# Cool Carousel - Not working with SlideToggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

i'm using the "Coolcarousel" Plugin in my page, he works nice, but if i hide the div container and use "SlideToggle()" to show the carousel don't start...

Here's the site [Link](http://sistemas.vilavelha.com.br/Newsletter/Ricardo/super-seguros/index.html#), help me please :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate the carousel in the callback after the slideToggle is completed. Then you avoid the problems.

Comment: Thank you ;) i made the call inside the click function and works, thank you again :D